# How can the Google App Script cards be styled?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

1. The following button always displays the text in all caps (SIGN IN).
   Is there a way to avoid capitalized text strings using
   CardService.newTextButton().setText('Sign in')?
2. Is there a way to custom-style the whole card with a particular background color?

Comment: The card styles are intended to be consistent with the base programs user interface which continues to remain under the control of Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't have better answers!

1. You can use an [ImageButton](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/image-button). Obviously a bit of a hack, but should still meet a11y requirements with alt-text.
2. This is not currently possible as far as I can tell.

Please [file separate feature requests](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) for each of these.